# Homogeneous polynomials on complex projective line

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, projective-space

I am working with some (holomorphic) sections of line bundles over the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$, these can be seen to be taken as homogeneous polynomials in two complex variables
$$
p \in H^0(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathcal{O}(d)) \simeq S^d(\mathbb{C}^2)^*.
$$
I want to write them in some canonical form by changing my homogenoeus coordinates, ideally  writing
$$
p' = g^*p = a x_0^k x_1^{d-k}
$$
where $g$ is a change of coordinates (I think an element of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$). Two questions:

**Question 1**: is it possible to do this? Is there a constructive manner? I have been playing around with some low degree polynomials but I get stuck at elements like
$$p=x_0^3 - x_1^3 = (x_0 - x_1 \xi_1)(x_0 - x_1 \xi_2)(x_0 - x_1 \xi_3),$$
where $\xi_i$ are the 3 cube roots of 1.

**Question 2**: if such a thing is always possible... how many polynomials can I write in my preferred canonical form with a single change of coordinates? I think this has to do with the degree of transitivity of the action of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. The section
$$x_0^k x_1^{d-k}$$
has a $k$-th root at $0$ and a ($d-k$)-th root at $\infty$. But as you noted, your polynomial
$$p = x_0^3 - x_1^3$$
has three distinct roots $1, \xi$ and $ \xi^2$. If
$$g: \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$$
is any isomorphism, the polynomial $g^* p$ will also have three distinct roots, so it can never be of the form $x_0^k x_1^{d-k}$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I am grasping at the origin of my confusion: I do not want to implement "canonical form of sections" by moving around the base: I need to find how $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ acts on the line bundle itself (I think that is called a linearization), and so not only will I change coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^1$: I will be changing the trivializations of the bundle.

Comment: @topolosaurus Ah, you want a linearization. I'm not sure your attempt will be fruitful. Mumford explains in *Geometric Invariant Theory*, Chapter 1 §3, that there is no $PGL(n+1)$-linearization of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$. You either have to work with the group $SL(n+1)$, or with the line bundle $\mathcal O(n+1)$. So I wouldn't expect this to work for general $\mathcal O(d)$.